# Recover Deleted Exchange Account Contact from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

So I removed an Exchange account from my iPhone not realizing that the phone had been saving new contacts there by default (instead of to my gmail account).  I no longer have access to that Exchange account, so re-adding it is not an option.

Is there any way to recover the contacts (and export them to a CSV or some other format so I can add them to Gmail)?

Also, the phone was never upgraded to iOS 6, so it's still running iOS 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding the question correctly:

- You had an Exchange account set up on iPhone.
- Contacts were being saved to the Exchange account instead of your Google account (also set up on the phone)
- You removed the Exchange account and no longer have access to it
- You need a contact you added to the Exchange account

Assuming all of the above is accurate, then no, there is no way to retrieve it.